# Using jmeter how to login as a user

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter for load testing purposes.

I need to check by logging in as a user in my testing server.

I have two HTTP Requests - one is having GET method and the other is having POST method with parameters - username and password.

When I execute the script the first HTTP Request is accessing the page but in the second request it is not logging in with the parameters added.

I tried by adding 'HTTP Cookie Manager' both inside and outside the Thread Group but it didn't work.

I use View Results Tree to check the Response Data.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

HTTP Header Manager inside the http request.